# How do I register a class for the change_form.html in the admin template and use the key of the object?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm using django 1.6 with python 2.7.6

In admin.py, I have some functions like def getJson(id) that takes an id and does lots of stuff with a model from the db and returns a JSON as string.

How do I pass this to the change_form.html ? (I have already overridden that file)

To do stuff with the list, it's:
`admin.site.register(Object, ObjectAdmin)`
and then I do stuff in class ObjectAdmin

But if I want to access admin/appName/Object/123 , how do I pass that 123 id to a class to use my defined function getJson(id) ?

should it be something like `admin.site.register_single(Obj, ObjAdmin)
and then I have some sort of access to a obj_key in class ObjAdmin?

I don't want to make all the stuff that getJson does in the template, because the function is long and it would not make sense either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view) is pretty clear about this:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    # A template for a very customized change view:
    change_form_template = 'admin/myapp/extras/openstreetmap_change_form.html'

    def get_osm_info(self):
        # ...
        pass

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        extra_context['osm_data'] = self.get_osm_info()
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id,
            form_url, extra_context=extra_context)
```

Comment: awkward... I missed that apparently. Thanks so much for taking the time to help, really!